# AngularJS 1.6 popver on dynamic data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am working on AngularJs components and I am having following requirement.

I have list of Person and I want to show them in `<ul> <li>` and it when someone popover it it should show one popover with details of that person like FullName, Profile Picture, Job Role etc

How can I do this?

Comment: Well since you managed to figure out which tags to put (angularjs, ui-bootstrap) I would advise you to try it yourself on plunker or fiddle, post your solution and then if it's not working ask a question. Just a hint, there's a uib-popover directive under ui-bootstrap: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#popover

Comment: Yeah this was helped a lot... Thanks